# upgrade from pandas 1.1.5 to latest version

Tags: python, pandas, upgrade

### simply not able to upgrade Pandas,
tried below

### python --version
Python 3.6.8

pip3 install --upgrade pandas

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)

---

### still the version is
Name: pandas
Version: 1.1.5

help please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas 1.2 and above does not support python 3.6 https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#increased-minimum-version-for-python

you will need to install a later version of python to use a newer version of pandas